# Is there a way to log python print statements in gunicorn?

Tags: python, debugging, logging, bottle, gunicorn

With my Procfile like this:

```
web: gunicorn app:app \
    --bind "$HOST:$PORT" \
    --error-logfile "-" \
    --enable-stdio-inheritance \
    --reload \
    --log-level "debug"
```

is it in any way possible to get python `print` statements to be logged to stdout / bash? I am using the `bottle` framework here as well, if that affects anything.

Comment: The debug flag doesn't apply to gunicorn. It actually fails if you try to run it:
`gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: --debug`

Comment: @Akronix thanks, checked in the [docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#settings) and can't find the --debug either; maybe it was never supported but didn't cause an error, or it has since been removed. Deleted it from the question, just so there's no incentive to copy it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It turns out the `print` statements were actually getting through, but with delay.

The [gunicorn docs for --enable-stdio-inheritance](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#enable-stdio-inheritance) note to set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`, which I thought I had, but it seems with wrong syntax.

I solved it using a `.env` file with my `foreman` setup to set the variable like this:

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
```

Comment: Even though it is official way to do it - it does not work for unknown reason (python 2.7)

Answer (score 57):

In python 3, adding `flush=True` in each print statement works for my flask/gunicorn app.

E.g.

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 server --log-level debug
```

No particular flags are required.

See if this helps.

Comment: It doesn't seem convenient to change the app code to work around this.

Comment: adding flush=True to print() also worked for me with gunicorn

Answer (score 44):

Please try below command:

```
gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/error.log --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/access.log --capture-output --log-level debug
```

It did work for me.

1. Specify [`--log-level`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#loglevel) to `debug`(default `info`).
2. Specify [`--capture-output`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#capture-output) flag (default false).

You should be able to watch logs in error log file.

Comment: No way to auto create it? `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/log/gunicorn/error.log'`

Comment: is there a way to redirect all stdout and stderr to a separate file than what's specified in `--error-log`?

Comment: @satys It doesn't work when it starts with systemctl service. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 16):

I use Python3 along with Flask.

I use `print('log info')` directly instead of `print('log info', flush=True)`.

I only set `capture_output` to `True` and set a `errorlog` file and it works.

Note [that](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#capture-output):

> #### capture_output
>
> `--capture-output`
> `False`
> Redirect stdout/stderr to specified file in **errorlog**

I think it's that you need to specifiy a **errorlog** file to get the standard output.

---

Here's my config file `gunicorn.config.py` setting

```
accesslog = 'gunicorn.log'
errorlog = 'gunicorn.error.log'
capture_output = True
```

Then run with `gunicorn app_py:myapp -c gunicorn.config.py`

The equivaluent command line would be

`gunicorn app_py:myapp --error-logfile gunicorn.error.log --access-logfile gunicorn.log --capture-output`

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me (I'm using a service called `si-ct`)

```
gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:si-ct.sock -m 007 wsgi:app --log-level debug --error-logfile - --access-logfile - --capture-output --reload
```

With that, the `print` output shows in my service logs, which I read using

```
sudo journalctl -u si-ct -f
```