# Number and type of Gunicorn workers and file handling in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am new to `python` and have just started using flask and building a web application that might need to handle 5 or 6 users at the same time. My flask app will trigger some `shell` scripts (based on user input) which might take 1 or 2 minutes to process and also it will mail the user about the stauts of their request. It will also write logs in a particular `.log` file for each day. Now I was reading about it and found out that I dont need to worry about handling multiple request as the `GIL` will not allow to run more than one instance of my application, even if I have 10 instances running at the same time. Now as mentioned in the `Gunicorn` doc `sync workers` will be able to handle only one request, I need to use `Async workers` but will it affect my application? Like writing to the `log file` and executing the `shell` scripts. Do I need to implement `locking` on the logfile and will it affect the `shell` script execution?

Answer (score 2):

**GIL**. It seems you don't need to care about GIL. GIL is about multithreading limitations, in your case, workers are independently running instances of your application. And even in the case of multithreading, GIL will be released when you will call your shell script, so that wouldn't be a problem either.

**AsyncWorker**. As I understood your design, will not help you, because you need actions (shell and writing log) sequentially, one by one.

**Locking**. If by each user request you'll run a separate shell script process and write to a separate log file then you don't need locking.

The core thing is that your application will be run by Gunicorn multiple times (workers count), simultaneously and independently. The count of workers depends on the user count you want to process and the type of your load, but values like `2 * cpu_cores_count` is almost always fit good. I would recommend `sync` worker type.

Also, I wrote a [blog post](https://weastur.medium.com/production-ready-gunicorn-config-b98574033e45) about production-ready gunicorn configuration. You may be interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Making my app sleep for sometime and then check if the log file and shell scripts don't have a lock anymore and execute that instance -- is it a good idea?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand why you need a lock. As I understand you want to write new log file per script run per user. If you are run multiple sync workers, then one worker will process one user. So while you are processing one user, another one can be processed too. You just run the script and write the log file completely independently. If you want to make one big log file with all the things, you need to print logs to stdout and then setup Gunicorn to write to file.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but there will be single log file for all the instance and the shell script that will execute by the instances might also be same depending upon the user input

Comment: Shell script isn't a problem. You can run it multiple times unless the script itself doing something that needs locking, but in that case, this will be the responsibility of the shell script, not Python, to do appropriate locking. Anyway, back to the logs. The most correct solution is to write to stdout in Python, and user Gunicorn settings like `capture_output` to save stdout/stderr to file. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687867/is-there-a-way-to-log-python-print-statements-in-gunicorn) can help too.